# How to make a USB device report as "device busy"?

Tags: usb-device

How can I make a USB device report as "device busy" indefinitely with a terminal command? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am troubleshooting a software problem using a USB drive that I think may present itself when the device is busy. I would like to test this scenario.

Comment: Do you mean so that the file system can't be unmounted (except for a lazy unmount)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple: Merely having a terminal opened in that location is sufficient to make the "device busy". You don't even need to execute a command.

If you can have several terminals, just navigate there in one.

If you use Nautilus in version of the last few years, you can just go to that volume, right-click it or right-click on blank space in its root folder or any sub folder, and choose "Open in Terminal". For old versions of Nautilus, this doesn't exist but can be installed via the package `nautilus-open-terminal` on Debian-based systems. Many other file browsers provide the same functionality.

If it needs to be a command, you can use this:

```
bash -c 'cd /your/mount/point && sleep infinity' &
```

This opens a bash in a sub-shell which switches to your mount point and then does nothing forever. This command will return immediately and the shell you executed it on will be usable normally.